# React Nginx Proxy Pass every file loading index.html

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, production

I've been scouring trying to find a solution, but when I go to my domain, all my static files are just returning index.html, giving me a

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` error

My setup is this:

A server that runs nginx for multiple domains, with the one site in question having the following config file

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;
        return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;

}

server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/domain/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/domain/key.pem;

        server_name domain.com www.domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://10.0.0.41:80;
        }
        location /api {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://10.0.0.41:3000;
```

where `10.0.0.41` is another server which is hosting 2 docker containers, one for my react app/nginx and one for my express backend app.

The reverse proxy to the express app works perfect, but when I try to visit domain.com, my js files are returning as index.html and not loading, giving me the error above.

When I visit `10.0.0.41` in my browser, everything loads as it should and works correctly, just not when coming from the domain.

this is the nginx config file for the second server

```
server {
      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html;
      location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
      }
      location ~ .(static)/(js|css|media)/(.+)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/$2/$3;
        }
}
```

I've tried everything I can find, adding that last line in the 2nd nginx config, removing, adding, changing `homepage` in package.json.

I am using React router, with `<Route exact path="/"`

This has been driving me crazy and any help would be greatly appreciated, and if I left out any important information let me know.

Difference in requests:

`10.0.0.41:80`

```
10.0.0.142 - - [02/Aug/2022:13:42:53 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 644 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.0.142 - - [02/Aug/2022:13:42:53 +0000] "GET /static/css/main.69847ccd.css HTTP/1.1" 200 2261 "http://10.0.0.41/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.0.142 - - [02/Aug/2022:13:42:53 +0000] "GET /static/js/main.10f72de5.js HTTP/1.1" 200 514201 "http://10.0.0.41/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.0.142 - - [02/Aug/2022:13:42:53 +0000] "GET /static/js/423.0a0d8ebb.chunk.js HTTP/1.1" 200 3280 "http://10.0.0.41/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
10.0.0.142 - - [02/Aug/2022:13:42:53 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 3150 "http://10.0.0.41/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

`www.domain.com`

```
10.0.0.101 - - [02/Aug/2022:13:44:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 644 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "my_ip, cloudflare_ip"
10.0.0.101 - - [02/Aug/2022:13:44:37 +0000] "GET /manifest.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "https://www.my_domain.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "my_ip, cloudflare_ip"
```

`10.0.0.142` is the machine i'm testing with, `10.0.0.101` is the first nginx server

Comment: Have you confirmed that going directly to http://10.0.0.41:80 works as intended?

Comment: Yes it does, everything loads properly when using 10.0.0.41:80

Comment: Ok, then a good next step could be to look at the output from `docker logs` and see what is different in the incoming requests in the two cases.

Comment: The differences I can see are the working request has `"GET / HTTP/1.1" 304` while the one not working is `"GET / HTTP/1.0" 304`, as well as there being more requests with the working one such as `"GET /static/js/main.10f72de5.js HTTP/1.1" 304`, which the request going through the domain only has the one request

Comment: Surprisingly the domain request is getting manifest.json, but no other requests for the js/css files

Comment: And if you open up the devTools when doing the domain request, where are the follow-up requests going instead of the right place? If it does infact get the html page properly, it should try to fetch the static assets also, so you should be able to see where it tries to fetch them from.

Comment: In the 2nd log example there's no static folder in the path. Ex. 1 shows a nice path with various static folders. Is there no static folder on the 2nd server? It wouldn't hurt to have default_type "text/html"; in your location blocks. I don't see any "root" path in the first server, is that normal?